# Server error (500) in browser

Tags: google-app-engine

I am encountering a 500 server error when I try to go to the GAE website I created to run ODK Aggregate (http://zambiawfp2013.appspot.com). I get the following message:

> Error: 500 Server Error
>   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>
> If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

I thought maybe it was a Mac OS X issue so downloaded the program on Windows XP but seeing same error message in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's an error in the server code, not the browser. Check the server logs for clues.

(i.e. skip over to https://appengine.google.com/, click on your app, then on **Logs** and look for E entries)

Comment: Thank you, but the server logs are empty..."You need to upload and deploy an application before you can make Web history." I have created the application but am unable to access the page that allows me to upload ODK Aggregate to GAE

Comment: So you haven't even installed the application?  Can you rephrase the question to make it clear that you have trouble installing the application, and describe what steps you have carried out successfully?

Comment: I have successfully downloaded and installed the application (ODK Aggregate) onto my computer. I haven't been able to upload the application to the GAE site. I successfully created an appspot.com address, but when I try to contact the site I receive the 500 error message. I read that going to the appspot.com address is the last step to upload and deploy my application to the GAE cloud. Thank you.

Comment: I meant editing your original question to make it clear what you're doing -- it currently doesn't mention installing ODK at all, so people who might know something about that application won't see it.